# Could not add dynamic data to the DataModel in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add dynamic items in Object[][] but it throws array index out of bound exception. I'm using the below code to do this,

```
private static final int CHECK_COL = 1;
    private final Object[][] DATA = {};
    private final String[] COLUMNS = { "Customer", "Selected Customer" };
    private DataModel dataModel;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel;

ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {

            Object obj = null;
            try {
                obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("json/customer_list.json")));
            } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray listOfBranches = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("customers");
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfBranches.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = (JSONObject)listOfBranches.get(i);
                Set keys = item.keySet();
                Iterator a = keys.iterator();
                while(a.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String)a.next();
                    System.out.print("key : "+key);
                    items.add(key);
                }
                System.out.println("Customer :" + listOfBranches.get(i)+"\n item "+item);
            }

            System.out.println("items array size :" + items.size());

            String[] customerArr = new String[items.size()];
            customerArr = items.toArray(customerArr);

            System.out.println("customerArr array size :" + customerArr.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < customerArr.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("customerArr array size :" + customerArr.length);
                    DATA[i] = new Object[]{customerArr[i], Boolean.FALSE};
                    dataModel = new DataModel(DATA, COLUMNS);
                    table = new JTable(dataModel);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting array index out of bound exception in this below line,

`DATA[i] = new Object[]{customerArr[i], Boolean.FALSE};`

Could you please suggest me an idea to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug and see the length of DATA element. DATA's length might be different from customerArr's length.

Comment: @user218046 both items and customerArr having same length. But i'm not sure about the DATA element length and I think i'm not yet initialized its length. Could you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index out of bounds exception you are getting is, as you pointed out, due to the following line:

```
DATA[i] = new Object[] { customerArr[i], Boolean.FALSE };
```

The problem here is the first dimension of the `DATA` array was never initialized, and so has a capacity of zero.  To resolve this, initialize your 2D array with the proper dimensions:

```
DATA = new Object[customerArr.length][];
```

Also, you are assigning only a single string to each *row* of your `DATA` 2D object array.  Perhaps this is not what you intended, but I would have expected an assignment along these lines:

```
DATA[i] = // some 1D array
```